Prevent specific key presses from being sent to foreground app using PyQt5 and pynput
So I want to detect certain keys being pressed and stop those keys being sent to the foreground app.
I don't want to use hideous libraries like pywin32 and pyHook as they are such a headache to build. So lets use pynput
The problem is no matter what I do - space does get blocked - but then the whole QTapp hangs - or worse I get a segmentation fault.
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, Key


class KeyListenerWorker(QThread):
    keyPressed = pyqtSignal(str, bool)  

    def __init__(self, configured_keys=None):
        super(KeyListenerWorker, self).__init__()
        self.configured_keys = configured_keys or []
        self.listener = None

    def run(self):
        with Listener(on_press=self.on_press, on_release=self.on_release) as self.listener:
            self.listener.join()

    def on_press(self, key):
        key_description = self.get_key_description(key)
        self.keyPressed.emit(key_description, True)
        # Block the key if it is in the configured keys
        return False if key_description in self.configured_keys else True

    def on_release(self, key):
        key_description = self.get_key_description(key)
        self.keyPressed.emit(key_description, False)
        # Block the key if it is in the configured keys
        return False if key_description in self.configured_keys else True

    def get_key_description(self, key):
        if hasattr(key, 'char') and key.char:
            return key.char
        return str(key)

    def stop(self):
        if self.listener:
            self.listener.stop()

class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, configured_keys):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("KeyListener Running")
        self.resize(300, 100)

        self.listener_thread = KeyListenerWorker(configured_keys=configured_keys)
        self.listener_thread.keyPressed.connect(self.handle_key_event)
        self.listener_thread.start()

    def handle_key_event(self, key, is_press):
        action = "Pressed" if is_press else "Released"
        print(f"{action}: {key}")

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.listener_thread.stop()
        self.listener_thread.wait()
        super().closeEvent(event)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    configured_keys = [str(Key.space)]  # Configure to react to the space bar
    mainWindow = MainWindow(configured_keys)
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


NB: So - according to the docs (and this SO post) (TY @musicamante) - you should use suppress=True..
but..
this leads to a hang..
class KeyListenerWorker(QThread):
    keyPressed = pyqtSignal(str, bool)  

    def __init__(self, configured_keys=None):
        super(KeyListenerWorker, self).__init__()
        self.configured_keys = configured_keys or []
        self.listener = None

    def run(self):
        # Listener with suppress=False: start without suppressing any keys
        with Listener(on_press=self.on_press, on_release=self.on_release, suppress=False) as self.listener:
            self.listener.join()

    def on_press(self, key):
        key_description = self.get_key_description(key)
        self.keyPressed.emit(key_description, True)
        # Suppress if key is in the configured keys
        return not (key_description in self.configured_keys)

    def on_release(self, key):
        key_description = self.get_key_description(key)
        self.keyPressed.emit(key_description, False)
        # Suppress if key is in the configured keys
        return not (key_description in self.configured_keys)

    def get_key_description(self, key):
        if hasattr(key, 'char') and key.char:
            return key.char
        return str(key)

    def stop(self):
        if self.listener:
            self.listener.stop()


As the documentation explains, listener.join() stops the listener as soon as it's released, which is exactly what you do when returning False, and that's probably not trying to do: you may need to call suppress_event() instead.

Aha thanks @musicamante related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65328213/how-to-prevent-certain-certain-keys-from-sending-input-in-python
and from the docs  class pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_press=None, on_release=None, suppress=False, **kwargs) "suppress: Whether to suppress events. Setting this to True will prevent the input events from being passed to the rest of the system."

Calling stop() and wait() inside closeEvent will prevent the window closing, since those methods will never return. In fact, there's no point trying to stop the listener on close, since that will happen automatically anyway when the Python process exits.

Ok. If anyone wants to know the answer - pynput is not your answer. Look at keyboard library. Note though this wont work on Mac - it causes a seg fault. Even with sudo
Here is some code..
import sys
import keyboard
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, QTimer

class KeyListenerThread(QThread):
    keyPressed = pyqtSignal(str, bool)  # Emit key name and press/release status

    def __init__(self, configured_keys):
        super().__init__()
        self.configured_keys = configured_keys  # These keys should be in the format expected by `keyboard`

    def run(self):
        # Set up hooks only for the specified keys with suppression
        for key in self.configured_keys:
            keyboard.on_press_key(key, self.on_press, suppress=True)
            keyboard.on_release_key(key, self.on_release, suppress=True)
        self.exec_()  # Start the Qt event loop

    def on_press(self, event):
        self.keyPressed.emit(event.name, True)

    def on_release(self, event):
        self.keyPressed.emit(event.name, False)

class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Key Listener Example")
        self.resize(300, 200)
        self.startKeyListener()

    def startKeyListener(self):
        # Define keys that need to be suppressed
        key_names = self.get_configured_keys()
        if key_names:
            if not hasattr(self, 'listenerThread'):
                self.listenerThread = KeyListenerThread(configured_keys=key_names)
                self.listenerThread.keyPressed.connect(self.handleKeyPress)
                self.listenerThread.start()

    def get_configured_keys(self):
        # Your logic to determine which keys to suppress
        return ['space', 'enter', 'right ctrl']  # Example keys

    def handleKeyPress(self, key, is_press):
        action = "Pressed" if is_press else "Released"
        print(f"Key {action}: {key}")
        
    
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        # Ensure all hooks are cleared when the window is closed
        keyboard.unhook_all()
        self.listenerThread.quit()
        self.listenerThread.wait()
        super().closeEvent(event)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


